# Pointer and structures

Tags: c, function, pointers, types, structure

I wanted to write a Code that scans the X and Y Variable and put it in a structure (with pointer) and then open a function where it should calculate the distance betweeen the points to the coordinate origin (dont know the english name sry).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

typedef struct
  {
    int x;
    int y;
    double abstand;
  }punktdaten;

void abstandsberechnung(punktdaten *punkt,int N);


int main ()
{
  punktdaten *punkt;
  int N;
  punktdaten hilf;
  printf ("Geben sie die Anzahl ihrer Punkt ein:\n");
  scanf ("%d", &N);
  if (N <= 100)             /* Es darf höchstens 100 sein, weil Aufgabenstellung */
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
     {
       printf ("Geben sie die X und Y Koordinaten ihrer %d Punkte ein:", N);
       scanf ("%d%d",&(punkt->x),&(punkt->y));
     }
  abstandsberechnung(&punkt,N);
    }
    else
    printf("Zu viele Punkte!");
}

void abstandsberechnung (punktdaten *punkt,int N)
{
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
     punkt->abstand=sqrt(punkt->x*punkt->x*punkt->y*punkt->y);
}
```

I dont know how to scan the variables and how to count up with structure and pointer.
It says that in line 29 there is a incompatible pointer type and in line 12 it expects "punktdaten *" but it´s "punktdaten**".

could you help me pls?

Comment: If you're looking for the distance to (0, 0), the name in English is indeed origin.

Comment: To fix the compilation error remove the `&` in `abstandsberechnung(&punkt,N);` - however then your code will invoke undefined behavior in `scanf ("%d%d",&(punkt->x),&(punkt->y));` because `punkt` is never initialized to point at anything

Comment: (In turn to fix this issue) You'll probably want to do `punktdaten *punkt = malloc(sizeof(punktdaten));` at the start of `main` instead of what you currently have and, assuming you don't want to leak memory, `free` it at the end of `main`.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could clarify what purpose `hilf` is meant to serve as it doesn't seem to be used.

Comment: hilf is for later to swap between the structeres. Structures with more distance to the origin put down in the list and with lower distance put higher. (i cut that part out so it would counfuse but forgot to delete also hilf)

Comment: After translating some of the text you print, you almost certainly want what @Barmar has posted as an answer---i.e., an array instead of my earlier suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dereferencing the uninitialized pointer `punkt`. It shouldn't be a pointer, it should be an array. Then you need to index it each time through the loops in `main()` and `abstandsberechnung()`.

```
int main ()
{
    int N;
    punktdaten hilf;
    printf ("Geben sie die Anzahl ihrer Punkt ein:\n");
    scanf ("%d", &N);
    if (N <= 100)             /* Es darf höchstens 100 sein, weil Aufgabenstellung */
    {
        punktdaten punkt[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            printf ("Geben sie die X und Y Koordinaten ihrer %d Punkte ein:", N);
            scanf ("%d%d",&(punkt[i].x),&(punkt[i].y));
        }
        abstandsberechnung(punkt,N);
    }
    else
        printf("Zu viele Punkte!");
}

void abstandsberechnung (punktdaten *punkt,int N)
{
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        punkt[i].abstand=sqrt(punkt[i].x*punkt[i].x*punkt[i].y*punkt[i].y);
}
```